# Cortar parte de uma Imagem usando uma lista de pontos de um polígono

Tags: python, opencv

Tenho uma imagem (ver abaixo) e uma lista de pontos que representam um dado polígono da imagem (ex. `contours=[ [1430,2003], [1429,2003], [1428,2003], .... ]`).
Desejo criar uma nova imagem que tem apenas este polígono (a nova imagem deve ser de um tamanho suficientemente grande para caber apenas o polígono).
Pensando neste problema, pensei no código abaixo. Contudo ele não é otimizado. Alguém pode me ajudar a implementar isso usando OpenCV ou tem alguma sugestão p/ otimizar?

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
img = skimage.io.imread(IMAGE)
....    
verts=contours[0].astype(int)
p = Polygon(verts, facecolor="none", edgecolor=color)
minx=min([x[0] for x in verts])
maxx=max([x[0] for x in verts])
miny=min([x[1] for x in verts])
maxy=max([x[1] for x in verts])
new_image = np.zeros([maxx-minx+2, maxy-miny+2, 3],dtype=np.uint8)
new_image.fill(255)
x1=y1=0
for x in range(minx,maxx+1):
    y1=0
    for y in range(miny,maxy+1):
        #point = Point(x, y)
        if p.contains_points([(x, y)]): # contains(point):
            new_image[(x1, y1, 0)] = img[ (x, y, 0) ]
            new_image[(x1, y1, 1)] = img[ (x, y, 1) ]
            new_image[(x1, y1, 2)] = img[ (x, y, 2) ]
        y1+=1
    x1+=1
cut_image = Image.fromarray(new_image)
cut_image.save('out.png')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

### Passos do programa

1. Carregar a imagem com o OpenCV
2. Cria uma cópia da imagem original para alterar somente a cópia e manter a original numa memória
3. Converte do espaço de cores BGR para escala de cinza, pois as funções utilizadas trabalham com escala de cinza
4. Utiliza Canny Edges para obter as bordas dos formatos
5. Encontra os contornos na imagem
6. Realiza Loop em cada contorno encontrado e verifica se a área é maior do que zero, que significa que é um formato geométrico e não somente uma linha.
7. Cria retângulos a partir das coordenadas dos formatos encontrados
8. Utiliza o Grab Cut para retirar o Background (fundo)
9. Cria uma nova imagem recortada a partir da região de interesse das coordenadas dos contornos

### Código de Exemplo

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imutils

def mostrar_imagem_plt(img):
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

def mostrar_imagem_cv(img):
    cv2.imshow('Imagem', img)
    cv2.waitKey(3000)

# Carregar Imagem
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS3i0.jpg")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/teste/qS3i0.png')

copia = img.copy()

# Conversão para escala de Cinza
gray = cv2.cvtColor(copia, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# mostrar_imagem_plt(gray)
mostrar_imagem_cv(np.hstack([copia, cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)]))
# Canny Edges, para obter as bordas
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
mostrar_imagem_cv(np.hstack([copia, cv2.cvtColor(edged, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)]))


# Obter contornos, para identificar cada formato geométrico
# verifica se está utilizando OpenCV 2.X
if imutils.is_cv2():
    (conts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# verifica se está utilizando OpenCV 3.X
elif imutils.is_cv3():
    (_, conts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Constantes do Grab Cut
bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)

for cnt in conts:
    #Informações de cada contorno
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

    if area > 0:
        print(area, x, y, w, h)

        # Retângulos ao redor de cada formato
        cv2.rectangle(copia,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
        mostrar_imagem_cv(copia)

        # Grab Cut
        rect = (x, y, w, h)
        cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

        mask2 = np.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
        gc = img.copy() * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
        mostrar_imagem_cv(gc)

        # Região de Interesse a partir do retangulo
        roi = gc[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        mostrar_imagem_cv(roi)
```

## Resultados

[image: Resultado 1]

[image: Resultado 2]

[image: Resultado 3]

[image: Resultado 4]